# how to keep eslint configs separate in monorepo

Tags: node.js, eslint, create-react-app, monorepo

I have project which uses CRA+Typescript for client side and Fastify+Typescript for backend. Problem is I put client and server code in two separate repository but now I want to keep both in same repository for easier accessiblity and I have eslint setup for both repository. How can I manage typescript or eslint configurations if I keep both folder in same repo. Is it bad to just keep both folder in a same repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A monorepo is a perfectly valid solution. Your eslint configuration does not have to be at the root level. You can define a separate config for your client and backend, place the config file in the root of those folders. You could have a config at the project root level with common settings and then have the two configs for your client and backend extend those.